# C - Polymorphic (void *) arrays

Tags: c, arrays, polymorphism, void

I recently tried tο find out the benefits of using `void *` arrays instead of typical types (`int`, `char` etc). So I tried to write a polymorphic `(void *)` function which takes as arguments 3 arrays (`a, b, c`) of any type of data and does a calculation between every node of array `a` and `b` and places the results into array `c`. The type of the calculation (sum, sub etc.) and the type of data to be calculated is up to the user (maybe we can use two more arguments to the function).

So I have the prototype of my function which looks like this:

```
void *apply(void *a, void *b, void *c, int calc, int typeOfCalc);
```

I cannot understand how to use the contents of every `void` array, depending on its type, and how to do the calculation depending on the type of data the user wants.

**EDIT**

I found an exercise which asks the same thing as I do and says:

> Write a polymorphic function `"apply"` that takes as parameters same
>   size tables (a, b, c) of elements of any (every) type, makes a
>   transaction between a [i] b [i] for each i and places the result of
>   act to c [i]. The act and the result will be produced, is determined
>   by the caller function.

Comment: You'll have to cast the array back to the proper type, depending on the calculation. So if your calculation involves floats, you'll have to cast the arrays back to floats. I'm gessing `typeOfCalc` conveys this information.

Comment: That's why I'd avoid "polymorphic" arrays...somewhere you'll need casts, copies and a lot of IFs...

Comment: In fact, the behaviour you describe is much better done in C++ than in C. If you really want this behaviour, and if you can use C++, use that instead.

Comment: I'm not really a fan of polymorphism but it's something i'd like to know. @Evert the typeOfCalc is actually what the user wants to produce from the calculation. For example before the call i have int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5} and char b[5] = {'a','b','c', 'd', 'e'} and the user says than wants to take the sum of these two arrays and result as characters..

Comment: Check [man qsort](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort), specially the example.

Comment: so array c after the call of the function must contain 5 characters, {'b', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'j'}

Comment: If you want to create such a function, you'll have to write an if-chain (switch) to allow for every possibility. You will also need to supply the types of a, b and c, plus the operation you want to perform. The `qsort` example suggests a slightly different way of going around this, where the operation to perform takes care of the appropriate casts, and is then in fact the answer supplied by Mabus [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25644496/707650). If you want this behaviour in C, just write a dozen different functions for each use case. Otherwise, I'd go C++.

Comment: @Evert There's no need to cast to convert a `void *` to any other data pointer. Please don't help spread that notion.

Comment: @Unwind How will you add two items from a `void *` array then? With `void *a` and `void *b`, can you do `a[0] + b[0]`?

Comment: @Evert No, of course not. You're going to have to use properly-typed pointers, or cast at the indexing point. The fomer might just be `const int *ia = a;`, no cast required.

Comment: Ok, but I tend to see that as an implicit cast from `void *` to `int *`, which works fine for `void *`. Perhaps "cast" is then not the term to use, though the pointer type changes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function pointer instead of typeOfCalc, which receives a, b and c. So, if you want to sum floats, you pass a 'sumFloat' pointer. You can also store a lot of function pointers (sum, product, etc) in a structure ('operationsFloat', for example) and pass that instead. Some code to illustrate:

```
void sumFloat(void *a, void *b, void *c)
{
    float * f_a = a;
    float * f_b = b;
    float * f_c = c;

    *c = *a + *b;
}

void productFloat(void *a, void *b, void *c)
{
    float * f_a = a;
    float * f_b = b;
    float * f_c = c;

    *c = *a * *b;
}

typedef struct{
    void (*sum)(void *a, void *b, void *c);
    void (*product)(void *a, void *b, void *c);
}Operations;

Operations operationsFloat = {
        .sum = sumFloat,
        .product = productFloat,
};

void apply(void *a, void *b, void *c, char op, Operations * opClass){
    switch (op) {
        case '+':
            opClass->sum(a, b, c);
            break;
        case '*':
            opClass->product(a, b, c);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm i'm a bit confused. How can i use the function pointer to determine the type of the result that the user wants, and how the  content type of the existing arrays? i don't think i have to use a structure or something..

Comment: I have added some code. Now, you can add integer operations, fraction operations or whatever you like. I think that this particular example don't show all the beautiful things that you can do with functions pointers, however.

Comment: ok so @Mabus in your example, when the user asks for a float result, the arrays have to be float too, right? but if i want to do a sum between an int and a char array to get a float result?

Comment: Ok, that's a VERY different case. In that case, you can pass three function pointers: aToCommon, bToCommon and commonToC, where 'Common' is a type that can represent all the values you want AND operate with them. So you convert a and b to Common, do the operation with Common and convert to c.

Comment: ok if you check the original post i edited before, you'll actually see what a same exercise asks for. I supose that i don't know the types of A and B, but i can have several arguments to do whatever i want. but the main idea (i supose) is how to find out the type of the content of the 2 arrays A and B, and how to properly typecast them to do the calculation i want

Comment: I think the exercise suppose that A, B and C are of the same type. If not, do as I said before: find a common superset of the possible types, and pass the function pointers to do the conversions to that type (and back again). If that type doesn't exist, you have to create it (and the functions to operate on that type).

Comment: well, finally i dont want to know anything about polymorphism. :/

Comment: @yakamuki Sure you do, but probably not in C.

Comment: yeah, that's what i meant

Answer (score 2):

Here an example getting an array of any type and using a callback function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum OP{SUM, SUB};

void calc_int(const void *pa, const void *pb, void *pc, enum OP op)
{
    switch (op) {
        case SUM:
            *(int *)pc = *(const int *)pa + *(const int *)pb;
            break;
        case SUB:
            *(int *)pc = *(const int *)pa - *(const int *)pb;
            break;
    }
}

void calc_double(const void *pa, const void *pb, void *pc, enum OP op)
{
    switch (op) {
        case SUM:
            *(double *)pc = *(const double *)pa + *(const double *)pb;
            break;
        case SUB:
            *(double *)pc = *(const double *)pa - *(const double *)pb;
            break;
    }
}

void calc(void *pa, void *pb, void *pc, size_t n, size_t size, enum OP op,
          void (cb)(const void *, const void *, void *, enum OP))
{
    char *a = (char *)pa;
    char *b = (char *)pb;
    char *c = (char *)pc;
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cb(a, b, c, op);
        a += size;
        b += size;
        c += size;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    #define N 3
    int ia[N] = {1, 2, 3};
    int ib[N] = {4, 5, 6};
    int ic[N];
    double da[N] = {4., 5., 6.};
    double db[N] = {1., 2., 3.};
    double dc[N];
    int i;

    calc(ia, ib, ic, N, sizeof(*ia), SUM, calc_int);
    calc(da, db, dc, N, sizeof(*da), SUB, calc_double);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("ic[%d] = %d\n", i, ic[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("dc[%d] = %f\n", i, dc[i]);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the OP intends for a, b and c to be arrays of n elements, not a 2-element array that sums (or subtracts) its two elements. So you might want to adjust your example a bit.